# Plotly.js: Any way to resize plots when sidebar is toggled?

Tags: javascript, html, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using a Bootstrap sidebar for my website with several Plotly graphs. The Plotly is responsive with window size change, but when I toggle the sidebar button on and off the graphs do not adjust properly. Is there a fix to this? Partial code for Plotly listed.

[Plotly chart not responsive -- extra space in the border when sidebar toggled off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaQt3.png)

```
var layout = {
              xaxis: {
                rangeselector: selectorOptions,
                rangeslider: {}
              },
              yaxis: {
                fixedrange: true,
                side: 'right'
              },
              margin: {
                l: 50,
                r: -50,
                b: 50,
                t: 30,
                pad: 4
              },
                yaxis: {
                  fixedrange: true,
                  side: 'left'
                },
                showlegend: false,
                

              };
              var config = {responsive: true};
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know when the sidebar has been toggled, you can call `Plotly.Plots.resize(yourPlotlyDiv)` afterwards.